# Alternatives to pig-tailing ground wires in outlet box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding-and-bonding

I have an old house and there are ungrounded outlets set in the baseboards. I am currently working on rewiring them and was wondering what the best way to tie the ground wires to each other and the ground screw is. From looking online, it seems to be using a pig tail, but these boxes are very shallow and I don't think I can fit a deeper one in there. So are there any safe alternatives?

Comment: Are you using existing metal outlet boxes?  Have you researched "self grounding outlets" ?

Comment: No they are shallow plastic boxes in single wall so there is no room to put anything else..

Answer (score 1):

I would use a crimp sleeve to save space.  Hold the ends of the ground wires together side by side so that one's about an inch longer than the other and crimp the sleeve on at the end of the shorter wire.  Loop the end, land it on the ground terminal, and you're all set.

Follow the instructions on the package of the crimp sleeves.  Most people use linemans pliers with a crimp lug to crimp sleeves.

[image: Ideal Linemans Pliers]

Comment: Do I need special tools for this? I saw a video on it and the comments seemed outraged that the guy just used pliers.

Comment: Strictly speaking it depends on the crimp sleeve instructions.  There is a Buchanon tool that makes the best possible crimp but most people use the lineman's pliers with a crimp lug.  See edits in answer.